# ARM Bootloader: value of "start_armboot"

Tags: arm, bootloader

In the U-boot for S3C24X0(ARM920T), we use following instructions to jump to C part:

```
ldr pc, _start_armboot  
_start_armboot: .word start_armboot
```

But how could I know the value of start_armboot? I couldn't find when or where we have defined the address value of start_armboot. It doesn't exist in the .lds file,either. Or because of

```
_start_armboot: .word start_armboot
```

we put start_armboot in the memory after the current position directly? Then how could we associate this instruction/address with the C function of "void start_armboot(void)"?

Answer (score 2):

`_start_armboot: .word start_armboot` just means to put the address of the symbol `start_armboot` at that location.

The linker is responsible for filling it with the correct address at link time.

Internally, `start_armboot` is just a stub filled with some dummy value (usually zero) when it is compiled into an object file. Later, when all the object files have been gathered together, the linker starts putting pieces together. Once all the pieces are laid out, it goes back through the object files and fills in the stubs since the symbol locations are known to the linker now.